# Mage::getSingleton()

Tags: magento-1, singleton

I am trying to learn Magento Admin Modue Development. In this regard I am following [this](https://magentomk.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/magento-create-custom-admin-backend-module/) tutorial. Here I got the below line.

```
 $statuses = Mage::getSingleton('web/status')->getOptionArray();
```

Now my question is `Mage::getSingleton('web/status')` referring which class??

Should I have `getOptionArray()`method in that class??

Comment: echo get_class(Mage::getSingleton('web/status')); paste this in app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php under indexAction() near line **48-50** you will receive a class name then you have to create a getOptionArray() method in this class.

Comment: if you followed the above tutorial and use the same namespace then your class name should be Company_Web_Model_Status which is going to be located at app\code\local\Company\Web\Model\Status.php

Answer (score 1):

It depends on modules configuration.
Each modules has a `etc/config.xml` file which defines where to locate Blocks, Helpers and Models. In your example you are looking for a **Model**.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        <models>
            <mymoduleid>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </mymoduleid>
        </models>
        ...
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```

This config file will tell Magento to locate all the class of type `mymoduleid` in `My_Module_Model`.

For example: if you call `Mage::getSingleton('mymoduleid/foo')`, Magento will translate it into: `My_Module_Model_Foo`. It is done in the following way: `My_Module_Model` + `_` + `camelcase of "foo"`.

To answer your question you have to locate the module defining the identifier `web` and locate the `models` section in `config.xml` file.

Otherwise, if you are in hurry, just place an `echo get_class(Mage::getSingleton('web/status'))` somewhere to see what is the class name.

Hope it helps.